# Synchronise two MongoDB collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 mongodb placed in 2 different servers. Each has a collection `items`.  The first collection has production data, and performs a lot of `insert` and `update`, the second one is empty.

Now my task is to transfer data from first to second collection, and to keep them in sync for few hours.

We **already implemented** the `oplog` solution. But since we lack of permission to listen to `local` collection in the first mongodb, we must find another way out.

One of the way I thought of is to create 2 services:
- In first call, I query all data from the 1st collection and transfer to 2nd collection. Then I save that data in memory.
- In second call, I query all data from the 1st collection, then using tool to diff them, then send the diff to 2nd collection.
- Repeat until one of 2 services is taken down.

The obvious problem is the huge waste of resources for querying and comparing data.

So I need your help to find another way to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

HP

Answer (score 0):

The solution you described in your OP:

> One of the way I thought of is to create 2 services: - In first call, I query all data from the 1st collection and transfer to 2nd collection. Then I save that data in memory. - In second call, I query all data from the 1st collection, then using tool to diff them, then send the diff to 2nd collection. - Repeat until one of 2 services is taken down.

... makes me think this is some sort of [blue/green deployment model](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html) or perhaps your intention here is to provide resilience in the face of losing the Mongo store for the first collection. If so, then I think the *correct* approach is to use a Mongo replicaset and let Mongo look after resilience for you.

However, I may be missing something ... perhaps there is some detail of your situation which (a) I have not been able to infer from your question and (b) demands some sort of manual, near real-time, copy from one collection to the other. If so, then I think the oplog solution **is** the common solution to this use case. Perhaps you should revisit that to see if you can overcome this issue:

> we lack of permission to listen to local collection in the first mongodb

If that's really not a runner then if you can intercept all writes to the first collection (i.e. if your application provides a throttlepoint or hook for applying behaviour to all writes) you could implement something like this:

- Before you proceed with the write wrap up the incoming command (i.e. the data and the type of write: insert|update|delete) in some sort of executable task
- Put that task on a queue
- Provide a thread pool which acts on these tasks, applying each task's command to the second colleciotn.

For example:

- Receive an INSERT with `data`

  - Apply this insert to the first collection (as you would normally do)
  - Asynchronously (so as not to adversely affect application throughput) apply this insert to the second collection
- Receive a DELETE for entity `123`

  - Delete entity `123` from the first collection
  - Asynchronously delete entity `123` from the first collection
- ... etc